# Android Spinner setTextview

Tags: android

I Search around the internet about "How can i change a TextView by setText if spinner's item is selected"

In my previous app i wrote a code that displayed a toast if a specific item on the spinner was selected
it was this

```
else if(pickuptimejava.getSelectedItem().equals(("Select Time in 24 Hour Format")))
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Select pick up time" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

}

it works totally well "Select Time in 24 Hours Format" if someone tries to register with that item the app will show an toast that "Select time please".

But if i do the same on my other app  like

```
if(pickuptimejava.getSelectedItem().equals(("Text view 1")))
        {
            textview.setText("THis is text view 1");
}

if(pickuptimejava.getSelectedItem().equals(("Text view 2")))
        {
            textview.setText("THis is text view 2");
}
```

it never changes the text. But in my first app it somehow recogonized the "Item" and it didn't let anyone pass without selecting the time. What do i do?

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    String quintity= String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem());
    switch(quintity){
    case "Text view 1":
    textview.setText("THis is text view 1");
    break;
    case "Text view 2":
    textview.setText("THis is text view 2");
    break;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
if(pickuptimejava.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Text view 1"))
            textview.setText("THis is text view 1");

else if(pickuptimejava.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("Text view 2"))
            textview.setText("THis is text view 2");
```